# DoS-атака и семейство операционных систем DOS

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки

На ru SO существует метка [dos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos), видимо, большинство вопросов по ней относятся к [семейству операционных систем DOS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS). Однако попадаются и вопросы о [DoS-атаке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DoS-%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0), т. е. DDoS-атаке, осуществляемой только с одного компьютера:

- [Эмуляция простой DoS атаки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/55006/199934),
- [Уязвимость к DoS атакам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/79937/199934).

Что предлагается:

- Использовать метку [dos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos) только для вопросов, связанных с семейством ОС DOS,
- Создать отсутствующую метку [ms-dos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-dos), применяя её к вопросам о соответствующей операционной системе,
- Создать метку [dos-атака](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos-%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0) или, как вариант, (по мне, менее предпочтительный) к вопросам именно о DoS-атаках проставлять метку [ddos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ddos).

Comment: Надо устроить dos-атаку на ms-dos :D

Comment: Думаю специальная метка ms-dos не нужна, лучше всё семейство - dr-dos, free-dos и т.п. объединить в одну метку.

Comment: для **dos атаки** правильно применять метку **ddos** от англ. Distributed Denial of Service

Comment: @perfect даже для атаки, которая не является распределенной?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov если атака не на нагрузочную стойкость то это обычный взлом и для этого достаточно метки `взлом` или `crack`

Comment: ps
пока не сталкивался с попытками атаками на ресурсы с одной машины но могу предполагать что инструменты для этого используют брутфорс-подобные

Comment: @perfect с какого перепугу атаке отказа в обслуживании надо назначать метку "взлом"?

Comment: @perfect навскидку, с одного хоста могут проводиться как минимум вот эти не являющиеся взломами DoS-атаки: атака медленного чтения, атака на пропускную способность канала в сетях на основе протокола RIP.

Comment: я слышал про такую атаку на ssh порт с одного хоста методом перебора брутфорсом. то есть брут досит порт вплоть до отказа обслуживания так что к нему не подсоединиться. брутфорс инструмент взлома вот я и сделал вывод. а насчет медленного чтения впервые слышу так мало опыта в таком вопросе возможно вы правы, но как мне кажется что современные средства все имеют технологию многопоточности, может это пережитки старых технологий хотя этим правилом тоже не стоит пренебрегать. насчет rip протокола тоже не знал хотя пожил уже не в одном десятке сетей.

Comment: мне тут идея пришла а почему все средства зашиты и атаки не назвать `хакинг` или `безопасность` или `взлом и безопасность`?

Comment: Правильнее давать не `ms-dos` а `dos-os`, ибо не все досы MS

Comment: @perfect если вы не сталкивались с DoS-атакой с одной машины, это не значит что её нет. Лично я в своё время пару раз вешал один слабенький сервачок с онлайн игрой на 10 минут. В итоге они арендовали более мощный сервер, обломав мне всё счастье, бяки. XD

Comment: @Ancient, прочитайте внимательнее пост. Метку `ms-dos` я предложил использовать только именно для MS-DOS и ни для чего более. Спасибо.

Comment: @perfect если отвечаете на сообщение - то указывайте кому отвечаете, иначе вашего ответа не видно

Comment: @perfect что же до многопоточности - так атака медленного чтения именно многопоточные сервера и укладывает (apache, к примеру).

Comment: а правильно ли я понимаю, что в силу ограничений движка SO, метки "DOS", "DoS" и "dos" считаются одинаковыми? И это нерешаемо?